# Adding Seconds to DateTime with a Valid Double Results in ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net

The following code crashes and burns and I don't understand why:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
double d = double.Parse("1332958778172");

Console.Write(dt.AddSeconds(d));
```

Can someone tell me what's going on? I just can't seem to be able to figure out why...

**EDIT**

This value comes back from the Salesforce REST API and from what I understand it's a Unix epoch time stamp. *"The time of token issue, represented as the number of seconds since the Unix epoch (00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970)."*

**SOLUTION**

Salesforce REST API is in fact sending *milliseconds* back for the `issued_at` field when performing the OAuth request when they say they're sending seconds...

Comment: What is the error/exception you get?

Comment: That double value can result in you trying to add `1332958778172.00000000000004` seconds(because of how doubles are handled) this would cause the out of range exception. Also this passes the number of years a DT can handle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As others have said, the problem is that the value is too large.

Having looked over it, I believe it represents *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch, not *seconds* so you want:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
double d = double.Parse("1332958778172");  // Or avoid parsing if possible :)
Console.Write(dt.AddMilliseconds(d));
```

Either that, or divide by 1000 before calling `AddSeconds` - but obviously that will lose data.

Comment: And you might be right, but the Salesforce API states that it's *seconds*. http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: Yeah, I just checked it, it's in milliseconds. I hate Salesforce so much, makes my life difficult every single day.

Comment: @Hupperware: Not just "somewhere in 2012" but "today" which seems to be a pretty convincing data point :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't like today :)

Answer (score 8):

The value you are adding results in a date outside of the valid range of dates that a DateTime supports.

DateTime supports 01/01/0001 00:00:00 to 31/12/9999 23:59:59.

A simple calculation of 1332958778172/3600/24/365 gives 42267 years.

Answer (score 3):

I think the double value is genuinely too large. It represents just over 42,267 years (if my maths is correct), and DateTime.MaxValue is 23:59:59.9999999, December 31, 9999

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0, DateTimeKind.Utc);    
Console.Write(dt.AddSeconds(1332958778172D));
```

Except that...

1332958778172/60/60/24/365 = 42,267 years... which DateTime can only go up to 23:59:59.9999999, December 31, 9999

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue where I was required to add a configurable timespan to a datetime.
If the configuration is not correct I have to assume the 'worst scenario' : MaxValue.

I solved it by implementing an extension to DateTime (still in test phase) :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Removes a timespan from a date, returning MinValue or MaxValue instead of throwing exception when if the resulting date
    /// is behind the Min/Max values
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static DateTime SafeAdd(this DateTime source, TimeSpan value)
    {
        // Add or remove ?
        if (value.Ticks > 0)
        {
            // add
            var maxTicksToAdd = DateTime.MaxValue - source;
            if (value.Ticks > maxTicksToAdd.Ticks)
                return DateTime.MaxValue;
        }
        else
        {
            var maxTicksToRemove = source - DateTime.MinValue;

            // get the value to remove in unsigned representation.
            // negating MinValues is impossible because it would result in a value bigger than MaxValue : (-32768 .. 0 .. 32767)
            var absValue = value == TimeSpan.MinValue ? TimeSpan.MaxValue : -value;

            if (absValue.Ticks > maxTicksToRemove.Ticks)
                return DateTime.MinValue;
        }
        return source + value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this timestamp is in milliseconds, try below code it should work fine.

```
DateTime nDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
double epoch = 1585008000000;
DateTime rDate = nDateTime.AddMilliseconds(epoch);
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me in a logic where the value added was `dynamically calculated` and it would exceed the `DateTime` range.

```
double expiredAfter = Math.Pow(10, value);
        
var expirationDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(expiredAfter + 5));
```

In my scenario `value` was starting from 1 and incremented at each step, and after 10 runs it would exceed the `DateTime` limit.

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to consume an api object as a double and convert the unix time to a DateTime:

```
DateTime Date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddMilliseconds(Double.Parse("1596225600000"));
```