# Unix Time conversion with powershell

Tags: powershell, unix-timestamp

```
Import-Module SQLite
mount-sqlite -name places -data (resolve-path C:\Users\malware_win7x86\Desktop\places.sqlite)
$places = Get-ChildItem places:\moz_places

foreach ($entry in $places)
{
    [datetime]$origin = '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
    $visited = $entry.last_visit_date

    if ($visited) {
        $vtime = $origin.AddSeconds($visited)
    } else {
        $vtime = 'testing'
    }

    write-host ""
    $entry.url,
    $entry.visit_count,
    $vtime
}
```

Reference: [Convert Unix time with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781697/convert-unix-time-with-powershell)

I'm curious on how to handle entries with no data.

For example, here is some output from that script:

```
http://sysforensics.org/
1
Exception calling "AddSeconds" with "1" argument(s): "Value to add was out of range.
Parameter name: value"
At line:7 char:28
+ $vtime = $origin.AddSeconds <<<< ($visited)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That error looks like you're giving `AddSeconds` an argument that is either too big or too small, rather than missing data.  Calling `AddSeconds` with either `$null` or `0` will return the original date unchanged.

That being said—and I can't be sure, since you haven't provided the actual integer that you're trying to convert—I had the same problem until I realized that the data I was receiving was in *milli*seconds, not seconds.  You can either use `AddMilliseconds` instead, or divide the number by 1000 before using `AddSeconds` if you don't care about the loss of precision.

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9914134/2498819) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In that case you'd just skip the method call and substitute a default value, e.g.:

```
if ($visited) { # or maybe $ivisited -is [int] or whatever your criterion is
  $vtime = $origin.AddSeconds($visited)
} else {
  $vtime = $null
}
```

Comment: I made some changes to the code. It still doesn't seem to be working. I keep getting the add seconds error. It's not printing any "testing" comments either on the items that don't contain $visited.