# How to parse a number to DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I get current time from http://nist.time.gov , it returns this value `1396677467961079` for today. but what type of value is that?

I tried this:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime();
dateTime.AddSeconds(val);  // val is of type double
```

But it throws an exception saying value was out of range. How can I convert that value?

Comment: You call a Webservice? There should be documentation.

Comment: `DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1396677467961079/1000d);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [Unix Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), commonly used in JavaScript / JSON.

Probably the best way to convert it is described into [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9914028/adding-seconds-to-datetime-with-a-valid-double-results-in-argumentoutofrangeexce).
In your case they are sending you the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch so you have to divide it by 1000.

EDIT: fixed the link and added a bit more description

Comment: and the code sample is like this: `var dateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1396677467961079 / 1000d);`